# Play! Framework 2 loads multiple databases very slowly

Tags: java, database, web-applications, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a series of MySQL databases which I have laid out in the conf/application.conf file of my Play! application. There is no default database, but eight other databases (used for regional setups for my web program) are all outlined in the following way:

```
db.<db-name>.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.<db-name>.url="jdbc:mysql://<database-name>:<port>/<table>"
db.<db-name>.user=<user>
db.<db-name>.password=<password>
```

With the above block being repeated eight times, once for each database.

However, on startup, this loads incredibly slowly (sometimes taking 5min and more to load all eight data sources). Am I doing something wrong here, or is there some limitation in the Play! Framework 2.0.X? And how should I fix this?

Thanks,
David

Comment: Are the databases hosted on a different machine(s)? Are they in the different network?

Comment: Yes, they're hosted in the geographical region, so separate machines and networks.

Comment: You mean separate geographical regions. latency of 5 minutes is still pretty high for just that.

Comment: That's why I thought it might be a non-latency issue, since I can connect directly to the mysql hosts through the command line almost instantly.

Comment: Just throwing stones in the dark, but can you enable more logs to debug (if not done already of course)?

Comment: Thanks for your time so far. The current logs are:

    logger.root=ERROR
    logger.play=INFO
    logger.application=DEBUG

Comment: also, have you tried changing between development and production mode?